# Is is possible in google sheet to protect certain columns, but allow rows to be added/removed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using arrayformulas to populate certain columns of my sheet, depending on values in other sheets. Occasionally users accidentally will put some value in these columns, and this will stop **arrayformula** from working. I want to protect these columns, but still allow adding/editing/deleting rows.

Consider this example spreadsheet: I want **Id** row to be protected, but allow addition/deletion of rows.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dnj7OE5XZL09gllHVwPgv-5GRoM-lxVCxTCI_-kURdM/edit#gid=0

Is this possible at all with Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't directly disable input but you can use Data Validation instead

By going to **Data > Data Validation** and filling it with the following:

**Cell range:** YourSheet!C2:C

**Criteria:** Custom formula is - =C2:C = A2:A & "["&B2:B&"]"

**On invalid data:** Reject input

**Appeareance:** Optional message

Once you've done this, try to fill some cell in the C column and you'll see a message: **There was a problem - Your optional message**

### As a different approach you can use Apps Script Simple Triggers

By going to **Tools > Script Editor** and copying the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (column === 3) {
    e.range.setValue("");
  }
}
```

Which is more like an "undo" function.

### References

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[Event Objects > onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Well, I don't want to use apps script, cause I have a lot of these so I'll have to implement some way to programmatically add trigger code to them or re-clone them, which is possible but a lot of effort.

First solution however is brilliant, the only flaw is that all of the cells included in range are invalidated, so show red triangle in the corner(see my sheet) which would become very messy cause I have a lot of such columns. Is there a way to disable this annoying red triangle?

Comment: Hello, yes it's possible to do so, I just wanted to provide an idea in this specific case please take a look into the new edit.

Comment: To remove red triangles, use correct check formula, 
`= C2 = A2 & "["&B2&"]"`

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered a long ago.
Just want add some correction and also a different approach.

As for the red marks in solution, custom formula has to be
`= C2 = A2 & "["&B2&"]"` then it works good.

Also there is a different approach. Works good if no need of the column to be seen. Just lock the cell with arrayformula. Then hide this column.

Answer (score -1):

rows could be added by brute force with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(A:A)+1)))
```

but escalation cant be controlled

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. It just spams rows. I need to figure out if it's possible to lock columns without disabling ability for users to manipulate rows.